# Unexpected session shutdown on java web project

Tags: java, linux, session, tomcat6

I have a Java web application that runs on Server Tomcat 6 installed on a linux server.
I have a problem with sessions.
When are logged about 100 users happens that some of them loss session before the expiration of TimeToLive.
I have setted the session live time of 30 minutes.

I think this is because of some settings in linux server or tomcat that limits the number of the simultaneous alive sessions but I don't know where to search.
Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.